# Sqlite implementation for console Dart application

Tags: dart

I'm wanting to test sqlite in dart, however the only implementation that I could find is by Sam McCall on Github, however it's out of date. While I could attempt to bring it up-to-date, I'm not very familiar with Dart yet.

I also read but haven't been able to confirm that sqlite access is provided in the VM, but only for non-html programs. The quote where I read that says "There may be additional problems, because the Dart executable now includes the sqlite library, as part of NSS (Network Security Services, from Mozilla), which is used to implement secure sockets in dart:io.". As I said, I'm not sure if this is correct.

I want to use sqlite with "dart:html", and "dart.io" can't be used with "dart.html", however using it in a console application would be a start.

While dart provides indexed_db, I don't see that as a replacement for sql. Also, while database access may be considered mainly a server-side requirement, there is obviously also the need on the client (eg. when offline etc.).

There would also be the possible problem of conversion to js, but that is not a concern of mine.

Any help with this would be much-appreciated.

Comment: Using SQLite with `dart:html` is a no-go. The `dart:html` library is made for programming in the browser (and in fact, is only available in the browser). And when programming in the browser, you are limited to what the browser provides you. There is IndexedDB, and that's pretty much it. In the past, there was WebSQL, which essentially was SQLite in the browser, but that's history.

Comment: What about outside the browser, or inside the browser connected to a local Dart server? The problem that I found with Indexed_db is that while it can probably do most or all of what I want, when it comes to maintenance outside of the application, I want and probably need to use sql. Then, there is Dart server-side and sql access to be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ladislav mentions, you cannot use sqlite with dart:html, because browser-based apps can only access what the browser platform provides.

WebSQL is basically Sqlite. It still exists, is well supported on mobile, but the spec is dead. It should work fine if that's what you want.

For command-line Dart, you may want to check out SqlJocky, which is MySQL drivers for Dart command-line VM. Check it out here: https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Seth. I'm a novice at this stage, however, I think browser SQL support is essential (for some applications). Your comments re WebSql and 3rd party are noted. I accept that Goog is paying for it, and it must meet their needs first. BTW, Dart is fantastic - 21st century (IMHO).

Comment: Seth, you may be aware of the following. Is it relevant? "Note that sqlite is now statically linked into the Dart executable, as part of secure networking support, but it is not exposed to the user (or to extensions?). If this extension was really useful, it would be nice to see if it could be made to use the library already in the executable.  This may not be possible, though.  There might be a security problem, or we don't expose the library functions for linking to the extension.  Note that we do expose the Dart API functions, which are in the executable, to the extension, though. .."

Comment: Brian, I was not aware. Interesting!